# Tensowflow 2.0: Multiple Inputs of type tf.data.Dataset and ImageDataGenerator Fails

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am predicting house prices using Deep Learning with Tensorflow 2 libraries.

I have data for 3 attributes (baths, bedrooms, area), and image of  each house as my dataset. (nearly 2000 samples)

I am building 3 Deep Learning models:

1. Regression model (model_reg): using 3 attributes -- worked fine
2. CNN model (img_model) using images               -- worked fine
3. Combining above two models (model_combined)      -- erroring out

Regressoin model:

I built a Deep Neural Network (DNN) model uisng Tensorflow2.0 with 3 attributes as features and prices as labels.

I could fit the DNN and could predict the house prices.

Note: I used tf.data.Dataset combining X_train, y_train while building this model.

```
model_reg.fit(X_reg_train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS,
          callbacks=[stop_callback], verbose=1)

63/63 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3993 - mae: 0.4256 - mse: 0.3993
```

CNN Model:
Next, I build other CNN using house image as features and price as labels.

This too worked fine and I could predict the house prices.

Note: I used ImageDataGenerator from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing to build the generator.

```
hist = img_model.fit(
    train_images_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_images_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE , 
    validation_data = test_images_generator, 
    validation_steps = test_images_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE, 
    epochs = EPOCHS,
    callbacks=[stop_callback], verbose=1)

49/49 [==============================] - 59s 1s/step - loss: 1741.6321 - mae: 20.8221 - mse: 1741.6321 - val_loss: 755833241600.0000 - val_mae: 768718.3125 - val_mse: 755833241600.0000
```

Lastly, I merged these 2 models appropriately using Concatenate() layer.
Now I have 2 inputs that need to pass to the model.
Hence I defined a model using Functional API's with 2 inputs.

```
model_combined = Model(inputs=[input_layer_reg, img_input_layer], outputs=[output_layer_combined])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01)

model_combined.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
```

Till this point it worked fine and the generated model looks fine.

It's going error while trying to train it using fit:

```
model_combined.fit([X_reg_train_dataset, train_images_generator], epochs=EPOCHS,
          callbacks=[stop_callback], verbose=1,
                  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE )

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input:
 (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DataFrameIterator'>",
 "<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset'>"}), 
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Question: How to pass 2 inputs: tf.data.Dataset and ImageDataGenerator to Tensorflow model?

Comment: Can you also provide the model_combined?

Comment: ```img_model: for image based price prediction using input - train_images_generator. | 

model_reg: for numerical features for price prediction - X_reg_train_dataset |

and in model_combined I am trying to use the same 2 inputs in a list - [X_reg_train_dataset, train_images_generator]```

Comment: Yea but how did you construct the model_combined with functional API, what are the layers etc.?

Comment: Yes, I used Functional APIs

```input_layer_reg = tf.keras.Input(shape=(X_reg_train.shape[1],), name='input_layer_reg')

img_input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape, name='img_input_layer')```

The above are the same input layers used for individual models... and the same I used for combined model.

```model_combined = Model(inputs=[input_layer_reg, img_input_layer], outputs=[output_layer_combined])```

added a Concatenated layer to combine in between and 2 dense layers at end

Comment: As I know you can't concatenate a Dataset object to a ImageDataGenerator , it doesn't make sense maybe after processing you can concatenate the results this might work.

Comment: I need to build model combining numeric features and Images in one go... predicting house prices independently has already worked.

I modified the code to have another tf.data.Dataset for images too.
So I have 2 Datasets now - one for numeric data and other for image data

Though both the inputs are of same type, I am still not able to pass the multiple inputs to fit method ([X_reg_train_dataset, X_img_train_dataset]

Comment: And did it solve the problem?

Comment: Not solved yet. As cannot pass list of tf.data.Dataset. Still getting the same error:
```ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input:
 (<class 'list'> containing values of types```

Comment: Maybe you can try to give them as np arrays by np.asarray().

Answer (score 0):

```
model_combined.fit(ta,                    
    steps_per_epoch = train_images_generator.samples // train_images_generator.batch_size, 
    validation_data = test_images_generator, 
    validation_steps = test_images_generator.samples // test_images_generator.batch_size, 
    epochs = 5,
    callbacks=[stop_callback], verbose=1)

Epoch 1/5
36/49 [=====================>........] - ETA: 20s - loss: 0.4512 - mae: 0.4512 - mse: 0.5005
```

I had to write a custom generator and a dataset on top of that to make it work

```
ta = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(train_image_dataset_generator, 
                                   output_signature=(
        (tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5,), dtype=tf.float64),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, None), dtype=tf.float64)),
        (tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64)),
    )).repeat()

def train_image_dataset_generator():
    data_X_reg = enumerate(X_reg_train_dataset)
    a_tuple = next(data_X_reg)
    b_tuple = train_images_generator.next()
```